# Apple Configurator 2 version and blueprints

Tags: apple-configurator

If I upgrade from version 2.3 of the Apple configurator 2 to the newest version will my be blueprints disappear?

Answer (score 1):

No they won't. However, if you are concerned about losing them, you can follow the instructions in the linked document to backup and restore blueprints:

- [Preserve or migrate data for Apple Configurator 2](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT207434)